# Transaction handle Database Design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am in a position to design my database for our e-commerce platform.We have different type of transactions in this platform like product purchase, service booking, events booking, Programs booking etc.All these sections are independent each other .

I have 2 options in my mind

1)Use a single transaction table to to store all transaction to the system and reference this table to other tables .Like service booking table has a transactionId field link to transaction table.

2)Store each transaction details to curresponding booking tables.Like event_booking table stores its transaction details ....

Which one is better?Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Which ever method maintains `referential Integrity` is better

Comment: Given that the transactions probably have different columns, the second option seems like the only reasonable choice.

Comment: Make if fit your business logic.  This sentence `All these sections are independent each other` make me think no.2 is the best for your particular scenario.